# Can I create tiles in Qgis and upload them to Arcgis Online

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online, tiles

I have a large shapefile that I want to convert to tiles. Now I need to load those tiles up to Arcgis Online, but I only have Qgis 2.8 desktop--since I work on Linux. I know that Arcgis desktop can load tiles directly to Arcgis online. But, am I able to upload tiles created on Qgis to Arcgis Online?

Comment: What is the size of shape file and what is the features count ?

Comment: So the file is 98 mb. There are only like 108 features, but each feature is a really complex multipolygon geometry.

Comment: When you are saying create tiles, you mean you will convert the vector data in shape files into Raster (tiles) ?   Why not you open the shape files direct in ESRI ? already it is straightforward in ESRI https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/publish-tiles.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_A2E4F9EB87454D84B66788D7D4C027EC

Comment: So the issue is the file size and loading time. I can load the shapefile to arcgis, but the Web display is really slow when   I zoom in or out. Arcgis online will try to redraw all of the vector features. So by tiling I should be able to zoom in and our with less delay.

Comment: Already the publish feature allow you to create tiles, read the below section: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/publish-tiles.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_A2E4F9EB87454D84B66788D7D4C027EC

Comment: Yeah there is a feature in arcgis online to create tiles,  but there is a charge each time you do that. So I was hoping to create the tiles in qgis and upload them to arcgis online. Otherwise I will spend a lot of money on trial and error.

Comment: Did you check the below library ?http://alephnull.net/software/gis/tile_writer.shtml

Comment: Thanks @Shady I will check out that library. I was just wondering if there was a way for me to upload the tiles that I create in Qgis into Arcgis online? Like would I need to create an image service, or is there some other way for me to upload those tiles? Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Do you have your own server ?

Comment: I do have my own arcgis server. ESRI hosts the server, but I am an admin. The ESRI tiling service costs a bunch of credits so wanted to not use up all of my credits

Comment: You mentioned the shape file rendering in the web is slow, did you try to create spatial index for the shape file before you Publish on ArcGIS online ?